# Second Order Differential Equation Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a linear homogenous second order differential equation $$y(x)-p(x)y'(x)-y''(x)=0$$
where $p(x)$ is a positive continuously differentiable function (i.e. $p(x)\geq 0$) with linear growth (i.e. there exists an $M>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|p(x)|\leq M|x|$ for all $x>\delta$), $y'(x) \geq 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y'(x)= 0$. Suppose we know that there exists a twice continuously differentiable. I am trying to show that any solution to $y$ with linear growth satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x)=0$.

I was able to show this for the case of $p(x)$ a negative linear growth function by contradiction as follows. Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x)>0$. Then there exists an $\epsilon, \delta>0$ such that for $x>\delta$, $y(x)>\epsilon$. Then by $p(x) \leq 0$ and $y'(x) \geq 0$, $y''(x)>\epsilon$ for $x>\delta$. This implies $y'(x) \geq \epsilon x \rightarrow \infty$, which contradicts linear growth.

Comment: I don't think that this is true. Here's [a plot of solutions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0nmi6fzqi4) of the O.D.E. with $p(x) = x - \frac{2}{x} < x$ for all $x > 0$, which appear to be unbounded.

Comment: What about a p(x) with a growth rate less than one?

Comment: You might want to add some more restrictions on what linear growth means in order to get the desired question, considering that $p(x)=-x^2$ would have "linear growth" under the current definition. Maybe you could have something like "$\frac{p(x)}{x}$ converges" for linear (and sub-linear) growth. And I think it's false even with that when $p(x)-x\to0$. It might be true for growth rates less than one though.

Comment: The question is equivalent to asking: For all functions $y(x)$ with linear growth and $y''(x)+p(x)y'(x)-y(x)=0$ and $\lim y(x)\not=0$, is it true that the solution for $p(x)$ (which would be $\frac{y(x)-y''(x)}{y'(x)}$) doesn't have linear growth?

Comment: If you look at it as mechanical system (mass with spring + damper), then $y''+p y' + k y=0$ will have output that goes to zero if $p>0,k>0$. This is because $p$ represents damping and $k$ the stiffness. For positive values, these take energy out of the system, hence it will eventually stop. But if you have negative $p$ or negative $k$ then output  does not necessarily go to zero (because one of these adds energy into the system, and one takes it out., so it depends).  In real world physical systems, damping and stiffness are positive,

Comment: You write "...such that $|p(x)|\leq M|x|$ for all $x>\delta$". Should it be $|x|>\delta$ or does that mean that the case $x\to+\infty$ is considered? Also $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} y(x)=0$ and $y'(x)\ge0$ is possible only if $y\equiv0$.